# Linking CUDA code with C code with mutual dependency and extern variables

Tags: c, cuda, g++, circular-dependency, nvcc

I have the following files with mutual dependencies on each other:

**some_code_main.c**

```
#include "utils.h"
#include "cmdline.h"

FILE log;
struct gengetopt_args_info args_info;

extern int abc;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    initialize_files(&log, &error_log);  // Some helper function

    cmdline_parser(argc, argv, &args_info); // From cmdline.h

    some_utility_function();    // From utils.h

    cuda_function();    // From cuda_code.cu
}
```

**utils.c**

```
int abc;
extern FILE *LOG;

void some_utility_function() {
    // Calculate abc.

    fprintf(LOG, "abc is %d", abc);
}
```

**cuda_code.cu**

```
extern int abc; // From utils.c
extern struct gengetopt_args_info args_info;
extern FILE *LOG;

__global__ void some_kernel(char * input, int some_value, int dev_abc) {
    // Process input.
}


void cuda_function() {

    char * input;
    char * dev_input;

    cudaMalloc();

    int some_value = args_info.some_value;

    some_kernel<<<5, 5>>>( dev_input, some_value, abc );

    cudaMemcpy( input, dev_input, some_size), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    cudaFree()

    fprintf(LOG, "%s", input);

}
```

So some_code_main.c depends on utils.c and cuda_code.cu; utils.c depends on some_code_main.c; cuda_code.c depends on both some_code_main.c and utils.c.

If there were no such circular dependencies, I understand that I could compile the code by defining a prototype for cuda_function() in some_code_main.c and then using something like:

```
all:
    some_code-mt

some_code-mt: cuda_code.o
    g++ -o some_code utils.c some_code_main.c cuda_code.o

cuda_code.o:
    nvcc -c cuda_code.cu
```

But because cuda_code.cu (compiled with nvcc) needs some_code_main.c and utils.c (both compiled with g++) and some_code_main.c needs cuda-code.cu, how do I ensure that all the dependencies are met and the code compiles correctly?

Comment: I don't see any "circular dependencies". Just compile all the objects and link them as you are doing. But be aware that you will need to manually specify the required CUDA libraries and paths to gcc in order for the linking to succeed and be aware of symbol mangling using g++ to compile C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, I just had to manually specify CUDA libraries and paths and it worked fine:

```
g++ -o some_code utils.c some_code_main.c cuda_code.o -L/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64 -lcudart -pthread
```